# Firefox start Performance Recording on refresh

Tags: firefox, performance-testing, page-refresh, firefox-developer-tools

How can I start a Performance Recording on a page refresh? Currently I can start a recording and then manually refresh the page, which leaves some time representing the page before the refresh.